# cannot import name 'component' from 'spacy' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/spacy/__init__.py)

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, huggingface-transformers

I did the following installs:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/boudinfl/pke.git
```

and now I am getting this error:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-680c259694ed> in <module>()
----> 1 from spacy import component

ImportError: cannot import name 'component' from 'spacy' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/spacy/__init__.py)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Spacy 3.x does not have `component`. You can't use this import.

Comment: Were you able to fix this issue? Actually I am also stuck with the same package and same place! Please let me know if you get to know something about it.